# How to display indirectly given unicode character in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, unicode

In a JSON data file, I have a unicode character like this:

```
{
    ”myUnicodeCharacter”: ”\\u{25a1}”
}
```

I know how to read data from JSON files. The problem occurs when it contains characters which are represented as above.

I read it in to a String variable, myUnicodeCharacterString, which gets the value ”\u{25a1}”. I couldn't by the way use a single slash in the JSON data file because in such case it doesn't recognize the data in the file to be a proper JSON object, returning nil.

However, the value is not encoded to its graphical representation when it’s assigned to something for displaying it, for example a SKLabelNode:

```
mySKLabelNode.Text = myUnicodeCharacterString // displays ”\u{25a1}” and not a hollow square
```

The problem boils down to this:

```
// A: direct approach, does works
let unicodeValueByValue = UnicodeScalar("\u{25a1}") // ”9633”
let c1 = Character(unicodeValueByValue) // ”a hollow square”

// B: indirect approach, this does not work
let myUnicodeString = "\u{25a1}"
let unicodeValueByVariable = UnicodeScalar(myUnicodeString) // Error: cannot find an initialiser
let c2 = Character(unicodeValueByVariable)
```

So, how do I display a unicode character of the format "\u{xxxx}" if it's not directly given in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better way would be to use the proper `\uNNNN` escape sequence
for Unicode characters in JSON (see http://json.org for details).
This is automatically handled by `NSJSONSerialization`, and you don't
have to convert a hex code.

In your case the JSON data should be

```
{
    "myUnicodeCharacter" : "\u25a1"
}
```

Here is a full self-contained example:

```
let jsonString = "{ \"myUnicodeCharacter\" : \"\\u25a1\"}"
println(jsonString)
// { "myUnicodeCharacter" : "\u25a1"}

let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
            options: nil, error: nil) as [String : String]

let myUnicodeCharacterString = dict["myUnicodeCharacter"]!
println(myUnicodeCharacterString)
// □
```

Comment: Nice. Also allows for mixing "\uxxxx" types with "@", "$", "A" etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, which does not answer the question, but is actually a better way of doing what I'm trying to do.

The unicode character is given instead as its hexadecimal value in the JSON data file, stripping all escape characters:

```
{
    ”myUnicodeCharacter”: ”25a1”
}
```

Then it's processed like this, after reading the value in to myUnicodeCharacterString:

```
let num = Int(strtoul(myUnicodeCharacterString, nil, 16))
mySKLabelNode.Text = String(UnicodeScalar(num))
```

And that worked. Now the hollow square showed up.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, we can implement the following solution

let jsonString = "{ "unicodeCharacter" : "\u00BD"}"

let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
if let data = data {
let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: String]

```
print(dict?["unicodeCharacter"] ?? "")
```

}

Output: "½\n"