# Convert unicode symbols \uXXXX in String to Character in Swift

Tags: swift, string, unicode-string

I'm receiving via a REST API a string which contains unicode encoded characters in form of `\uXXXX`

e.g. `Ain\u2019t` which should be `Ain’t`

Is there a nice way to convert these?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `\u{my_unicode}`:

```
print("Ain\u{2019}t this a beautiful day")
/* Prints "Ain’t this a beautiful day"
```

From the [Language Guide - Strings and Characters - Unicode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> ...
>
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit
>     hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code point

Comment: I've seen this before, the problem is, I don't know where and which characters are contained in the strings returned.

Comment: @Dimitri As Leo says, I you know you have e.g. UTF-8 in hex, just parse the 4 characters following `\u` and replace with the answer given above.

Comment: @LeoDabus API is providing me the string. I will try parsing it. This sounds the most successful approach :) thanx

Comment: @Dimitri E.g. `let a = "Ain\u2019t this a beautiful day"` wont compile, so I wonder what API does with the invalid special character `\u...`?

Comment: @dfri I think this is the default JSON encode behavior.

Comment: @Dimitri: I see, then you should probably look into the `NSJSONSerialization` class, it should contain existing methods to handle unicode characters with escape suffixes `\u`(_prior_ to assigning this to a swift native `String` object). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318171/using-swift-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004561/how-to-display-indirectly-given-unicode-character-in-swift

Comment: @dfri Thanks, the NSJsonSerialization gave me the idea. So the problem wasn't the \uXXXX which was correctly converted by Alamofire.responseJSON (checked by printing it out). Instead I've used a transform during parsing to change it into an NSURL. This wasn't escaped.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, for your patience, my error was my transform as described in the comment above. Not with the unicode -.-.

Comment: @Dimitri Happy to hear you solved it, happy to help!

Answer (score 12):

You can apply a string transform `StringTransform`:

```
extension String {
    var decodingUnicodeCharacters: String { applyingTransform(.init("Hex-Any"), reverse: false) ?? "" }
}
```

---

```
let string = #"Ain\u2019t"#
print(string.decodingUnicodeCharacters)  // "Ain’t\n"
```

Comment: Excellent answer when you are handling strings you don't control.

Comment: In my case, Issue:  API response is Ain\U200bt , when u try to store in local variable as MyString from API, then if use label.text = MyString -->> Aint is showing, but., if we use attributed.text -->> Ain t is showing (Extra space).

Comment: @McDonal_11 `\U200b` is not the same as `\u200b`

Comment: YEs., but replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{200B}", with: ""), this is working., I dont know concept behind this.,

Comment: @LeoDabus decodingUnicodeCharacters not available, Any other option?

Comment: @SolidSoft  Did you add the extension to your project?